# Creating a factory in Angular with JSON data from Neo4j server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest, factory

I've been learning Angular with Neo4j, and I encountered problems dealing with JSON I get as a response to my query.

Now, I want to capture the data, and be able to use it between different app views (i.e. click to on a car of choice, go to view of that car), so in order to do it, I guess I need to set up a factory handling all the data. So right now, I have this.

My call to Neo, which I guess should also be in Factory and not controller.

```
function restcall($scope, $http) {

  var call = '{ "statements" : [ { "statement" : "MATCH (n:Cars) RETURN n ORDER BY n.initRank DESC LIMIT 10" } ] }';

  $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://myserver:7474/db/data/transaction/commit',
                data: call,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
                           'Authorization': 'Basic mybasekey' } 

 })
 .success(function (data, status) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                        $scope.response = data.results;
            })
            })

        };
```

This, works on individual cases, but what is more my problem is the JSON that I receive as a response to my call. It looks like this

```
{

"results":[{

    "columns":[
        "n"
    ],

    "data":[
        {"row":[{"name":"Car1","initRank":"..."}]},
        {"row":[{"name":"Car2","initRank":"..."}]},
        {"row":[{"name":"Car3","initRank":"..."}]},
        {"row":[{"name":"Car4","initRank":"..."}]},
        {"row":[{"name":"Car5","initRank":"..."}]},
        {"row":[{"name":"Car6","initRank":"..."}]}]
}],

"errors":[]

}
```

And now, because I only use rows from this json, I want to setup a variable, lets say cars, that will have this shape

```
 var Cars = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Car1',
        initRank: '...'
      }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Car2',
        initRank: '...'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Car3',
        initRank: '...'
      }, {
        
        // And so on until end of the result in rows
        
      }];
```

Now, to do this, I have tried to use FOR loop and add results to individual array members like

```
car[i].name = response.data[i].row[0].name
```

But it did not work.

So ultimately my questions are.

**1. How is my factory supposed to look?**

Is this ok?

```
.factory('Cars', function($scope, $http){
    //rest of my rest call from function
} )
```

I've seen examples with using $http.get(), but I do not know how to pass all the stuff I have now in my http (method needs to be post for db sake, my cypher call, authorization layer..), using http.get().

**2. How to format my response in order to have a nice `var Cars` ?**

And another thing that is bugging me...

3. Is it possible to pass specific row from factory without going through ng-repeat? If I want to access just Car3 for a case.

If not, like I presume, how to, if I'm reading Car3 with `response.data[2].row[0].name` **how to pass it to new view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How is my factory supposed to look?

- Your factory should return an object, that define your getCars() method.
- getCars() should return a promise.
- **Do not, pass $scope to services**. $scope is the glue between view and the controller.

  ```
  .factory('Cars', function($http){
     // return an object.
     return {
        getCars: getCars
     }


     function getCars(){   
            return  $http.get('http://myserver:7474/db/data/transaction/commit', {params:{"param1": val1, "param2": val2}}).then(function(response){
               return response.data.results.data.map(function(d){ 
                  return d.row[0];
               });
            })
     }
  })
  ```

> 2. How to format my response in order to have a nice var Cars ?

You can use, promises chaining, by returning a second promise, after the data formatting (making a proper cars), when the first (response from server) is resolved.

**How ?**

Already included this in getCars definition.

> Is it possible to pass specific row from factory without going through
>   ng-repeat? If I want to access just Car3 for a case.

Yes. just store the cars returned from your server in local variable in the factory. And, define a `getCar(carId)` method, that will look first in this variable, if, found it will resolve a promise (use $q), else, it, will make, the call to getCars() to get the data from server. And, then resolve the promise by fetching the cars local variable.

Comment: Thank you for very elaborate answer, I edited the question 1, as I have a further problem, where I have to pass the data to server with also containing authorization layer, as well as cypher query..  And I don't know how to pass it in http.get() So I would greatly appreciate if you can help me here with that.

Comment: updated my code,  you can pass your parameters to $http.get() as second argument. please look at the config. object in the angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http